# What is the variations?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Sorry for my poor English ,I don't know the precise mean of variations in the below picture .I think it like coordinate translation ,but I'm not sure .

Besides, if $\delta g_{ij}=v_{ij}$,how to compute $\delta g^{ij}$? I guess it should be using the $g_{ij}g^{ij}=1$, but I don't know what $\delta 1$ equal to .

Thanks very much for detail answer or hint .

Below picture is from the 199th page of this [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947).

> [image]

Comment: @John Ma  Whether $\delta g^{ij}=v^{ij}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $g^{ij} g_{jk} = \delta_{ik}$, differentiate both sides to find 
$$g^{ij} \delta g_{jk} = -\delta g^{ij} g_{jk} \Rightarrow \delta g^{ij} = - g^{ij} v_{jk} g^{kl}. $$

In general, this $\delta$ is a common notation used in the calculus of variations. If $g_t$ is a family of (metrics, functions, embeddings...), then 
$$\delta g := \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\bigg|_{t=0} g_t.$$

Comment: so, $\delta g_{ij}=-2R_{ij}|_{t=0}$ ? Besides, how to calculate $\delta\sqrt{det(g_{ij})}=\frac{v}{2}\sqrt{det(g_{ij})}$? I get a different result.

Comment: What did you try for $\delta\sqrt{\det g}$? @lanse7pty

Comment: @JohnMa  Yes, I get strange result. And it is a little complex for print...Let me try to write down it .

Comment: $\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\begin{vmatrix} g_{11} & ... &v_{1i} &...&g_{1n}   \\ 
... & ... & ... &...&...  \\
 g_{n1} & ... &v_{ni} &...&g_{nn}  
\end{vmatrix}}{2\sqrt{\det g}}$  , this is my result. $|\cdot|$ means $\det$ .